# Styling single element child using x:key inside Style.Resources

Tags: wpf

I'm from many yars of html and css, so when it comes to styling I search the same use patterns.
This time I need to define an external style that is used by a single element (like css's #id), and in automatic to the child elements differentiating them with x:Key->Style (or .class in css).
The problem is that i can differentiate only by the element type, and all element of the same type get the same style. The only solution that I've found at this moment is to use inline style or create a completely new style definition, but this reduces readability and long term manageability.

I need to make work something like this:
External style

```
<Style TargetType="DockPanel" x:Key="MenuPrincipale">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="some_class">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,40,5,0"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Xaml

```
<DockPanel Style="{StaticResource MenuPrincipale}">
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource some_class}">
        <Label Foreground="White">this is styled</Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Foreground="White">this is NOT styled</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I fail to see why you're not assigning the `some_class` directly to the first StackPanel and avoid all the DockPanel-related stuff.

Comment: With css classes you can define different styles depending on the parent element, and by tagname, class applied or both. It's very handy.
I can make it work in wpf defining two separate styles, but this way i would lose the possibility to group the code under one <style>.

Comment: except it's not. XAML has the concept of `DataTemplates` and `ControlTemplates` and people don't use Styles for these sort of things. There's also DataBinding which is utterly absent in HTML, therefore XAML doesn't really need that.

Comment: ok, I will go back on the books then

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking, but take a look into inheritance of styles, by using the basedOn tag.

Comment: I'm using basedOn too, but what I'm asking is to keep the style code all in one place in a hierarchical way, and apply it only to specific child element and not all the elements (in ths case all the StackPanels inside the DockPanel)

Comment: @fehu styles in XAML are not intended to be used in a hierarchical way. See my comment above. You can directly assign the style to the first StackPanel and remove all the DockPanel-related stuff.